# How to update specific form field in formik when value changes in redux store?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using formik in my react application. I have initialized all the form values from a state. But I wanted to update a specific form field if props in the redux store change. Below is my formik form:

```
<Formik
initialValues={this.state.branchData}
enableReinitialize={true}
onSubmit={this.formSubmit} >
{({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
    <Form >
        <Row>
            <Col lg="12">

                <FormGroup className="col-6">
                    <Input type="select" value={values.StateId} name="StateId" onChange={this.handleChange(setFieldValue)}>
                        <option value='' >Select State</option>
                        {this.props.stateList && this.props.stateList.map((item, i) => (
                            <option key={i} value={item.StateId}>
                                {item.StateName}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                    </Input>
                    {this.validator.message('state', values.StateId, 'required')}
                    <Label className="impo_label">Select State</Label>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup className="col-6">
                    <Field className="form-control" name="GstNo" type="text" maxLength="15" />
                    <Label className="impo_label">GST No</Label>
                    {this.validator.message('gst no', values.GstNo, 'required|min:15|max:15')}
                </FormGroup>


            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Form>
)}
```

Now, When I change state from the dropdown, an api will get invoke which will return gst no by state id. I want to update the gst no field with the value recieved from the api in the props. If the gst no received is null then I want user to input the gst no, but if gst no is recieved from the api, I want to update the gst no field in form with the value received in props and disable the form input. I cannot update the gstno in this.state.branchData as this will reset the form values with values in this.state.branchData.

Does anyone have any idea about how to achieve this in formik?

Answer (score 29):

You can enable enableReinitialize property of Formik to update the field.

```
<Formik
   enableReinitialize={true}
   initialValues={...}
>
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, @Msilucifer. This really saved my time! :)

Comment: Good solution, but the problem that it resets all the fields to the initial values.

Answer (score 2):

When data comes from `api`. You can just easy change value of field like this:

```
setFieldValue('GstNo', valueFromApi)
```

Comment: setFieldValue() is not accessible outside the formik form. Do you have any way through which I can access setFieldValue() outside formik form somewhere in componenetWillRecieveProps()?

Comment: you can call function inside ```formik``` and call it. Example:

```
<Formik
  ....
>
  <Form>
    {setGsNo(valueFromApi, setFieldValue)}
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

and on outside ```formik```:

```
const setGsNo = (value, setFieldValue) => {
   setFieldValue('GstNo', valueFromApi)
}
```

Comment: there minimum [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-cray-kq9l7)

Comment: sorry I didn't get your solution neither your codesandbox is working.

Answer (score 0):

I defined a state variable for maintaining the gstNo that will be fetched from the API based on the state id selected from the drop-down. Like this:

```
 this.state = {
   gstNo: null,
 };
```

So, when the API will get invoked and the response is received, gstNo props will be updated in the redux store.

`this.state.gstNo` will be updated inside the UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(), when `this.props.gstNo` changes. Like Below:

```
if (this.props.gstNo !== nextprops.gstNo) {
  let gstNo;
  if (nextprops.gstNo) {
      gstNo = nextprops.gstNo;
  } 
  else {
      gstNo = null;
  }

 this.setState({
   gstNo: gstNo,
  });
```

And to assign `this.state.gstNo` value to formik, I simply wrote this:

```
<FormGroup className="col-6">
    <Field
        className="form-control"
        name="GstNo"
        disabled={this.state.gstNo}
        type="text"
        maxLength="15"
        value={
            (values.GstNo = this
                .state.gstNo
                ? this.state.gstNo
                : values.GstNo)
        }
    />
    <Label className="impo_label">
        GST No
    </Label>
</FormGroup>
```

So as soon as `this.state.gstNo` would be having some value, it would be reflected in formik form's text field and the textbox will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use setFieldValue, When the API gets some value or any props/dependency value changes, you can use useEffect to handle it,
For Example:
I'm getting `setFieldValue` function as a prop from parent component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (
        values.parentCategoryId &&
        !categories?.data?.find(category => category.id === values.categoryId)
            ?.hasFurnishingStatus
    ) {
        setFieldValue('furnishingStatus', '');
    }
}, [values?.categoryId]);
```

Here the `furnishingStatus` is the name of the field for which I'm setting the value.

```
<Field name="furnishingStatus" component={RadioGroup} row>{...}</Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method

```
     useEffect(() => {
        // get user and set form fields
        userService.getById(id).then(user => {
        const fields = ['title', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'role'];
        fields.forEach(field => setFieldValue(field, user[field], false));
        setUser(user);
        });
    }, []);
```